# Simple nested object produces `SyntaxError: Unexpected token` in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript

How come this parses fine:

```js
{a:5,{b:{c:7}}}
```

But all the forms below yield `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'`?

```js
o={a:5,{b:{c:7}}}
```

```js
console.log({a:5,{b:{c:7}}})
```

```js
({a:5,{b:{c:7}}})
```

```js
var o = {a:5,{b:{c:7}}}
```

```js
var o = {"a":5,{"b":{"c":7}}};
```

Comment: None of these examples are valid json strings. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159 for how they must look like.

Comment: @leiropi The question is about Javascript, not about JSON. As JSON is an incomplete subset of Javascript that specifically has further restrictions on object keys, simply saying that this isn't valid JSON isn't actually helpful or relevant.

Comment: It is relevant because in these cases the correct Javascript syntax equals the json representations of these objects. Also you didn't even mention Javascript in your question.

Comment: @leiropi By that argument, you might as well make up a fictitious language spec and link to that as long as its "correct" syntax was technically also valid Javascript. Ignoring that, linking to a multi-page technical spec in response to a single-sentence question caused by a simple typo is still unhelpful. The question is clearly tagged as Javascript, which shows both under the question body and in the page title, and it explicitly mentions the "Chrome console", which parses Javascript.

Comment: My glass ball tells me that you were torn between `{a:5,b:{c:{d:7}}}` and `{a:5,b:{c:7}}` and still 'standing on the railroad tracks' when your decision to type hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your object literals have an error:

```
{
  a: 5,
//v--- a key is missing, so { is unexpected
     {
     b: {
       c: 7
    }
  }
}
```

Because of that, all codes should throw.

However, your first one does not.

That is because when the JS interpreter encounters a `{`, immediately guesses if it is meant to be an object literal or a block statement. If both cases are possible, it assumes a block statement.

That happens in this case as well, and if you look at it closer, it's valid that way:

```
| block statement                              |
| |label|number|comma operator|object literal| |
 { a:    5      ,              {b:{c:7}}      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Well if you take a look at this `{a:5,{b:{c:7}}}` we can see that it isn't a valid javascript object because an object should have key-value pairs.

`a: 5` is fine but `{b:{c:7}}` doesn't have a key.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I somehow missed that. Wow, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

type this into the console:

```
'hello', 'world', 42
```

The result is 42. You can read more about expressions like that [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)

The question shows that you were thinking this were an object expression, which it isn't.

The JavaScript parser cannot read thoughts. Opening and closing curly braces (`{`,`}`) mark start and end *not only* for object literals; they do that also for the body of a function, the body of an if expression, and more. How is the JavaScript parser supposed to find out what you mean, when encountering an opening curly brace? What starts here? An object? The body of a `function`? The body of an `if`? A sequence-expression (those are the ones I mentioned in starting)?

There are JavaScript parsers written in JavaScript (like [esprima](https://esprima.org/) or [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-parser)), which can help newbies and long-year professionals alike when "thinking like a parser" is required. Whether noob or pro, I recommend you get esprima and try out things like this:

```
esprima.parse('1,2,3').body[0].expression  // { type: "SequenceExpression", expressions: [ ... ]}

esprima.parse('{a:5,{b:{c:7}}}').body[0].body[0].body.expression // also SequenceExpression
```

or this

```
esprima.parse('{}').body[0] // BlockStatement

esprima.parse('({})').body[0]  // ObjectExpression
```

With esprima, you can get to the bottom of questions like, why `({hi:'petard',lo:'biere'})['hi']` works, but `{hi:'petard',lo:'biere'}['hi']` doesn't, or the question you had.

Answer (score -1):

it can be parsed but as different objects (the console prints the second only)
to be fixed: it needs to be in the format of key:value
e.g.

`{a:5} {a:5,b:4} {a:5,b:{a:4}}` but the one you have `{a:5,{b:{c:7}}}`
as `key:value` pair, you are missing for the second sub-object the `key`

so you need to assign something maybe like this:

`const o={a:5,d:{b:{c:7}}}` or stay to my second example above: `const o={a:5,b:{c:7}}`

think of it how it would look like trying to get each value in a javascript function

```
 const  o={a:5,d:{b:{c:7}}}  
o.a=5, o.d={b:{c:7}}, o.d.b={c:7}, o.d.b.c=7
```

Comment: Curious, why is JSON being mentioned? I would think you meant JavaScript object.

Comment: No, it is NOT ok as JSON. It has the same "typo" problem as JSON, not suprisingly, as JSON is even stricter. `JSON.parse('{"a":5,"x":{"b":{"c":7}}}')` will work (note I inserted "x"), but the original `JSON.parse('{"a":5,{"b":{"c":7}}}')` fails.

Comment: https://jsonlint.com/

you can validate the JSON here

adding the "x" to the original is the way to go, you need to restructure your data. to make it key-value pair.. you don't need just a JSON syntax that validates in that validator above

Comment: @evolutionbox sorry, just saw this, The JSON is the text base data that has the Javascript object syntax. a valid JSON will be a valid object. Validating the JSON with another tool like above, might give you more info on how it's invalid

Comment: I saw now the problem sorry, the console just validates the second part and ignores the first without throwing an error

Comment: I would guess: 
The first part is valid key value pare, the second will be separately validated, could be a function returning the second part of the key-value

the second validation is also correct independently (Therefore the print of it on the console) )

And the thing ended there without an overall validation